# Help understanding the Cartan connection/formalism in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the Cartan formalism in the context of General Relativity.

As I understand it given a pseudo-Riemannian spacetime manifold $M$ we can consider the group of spactime transformations $G$ which act transitively on it (in this case $SO(3,1)\rtimes\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$). We can also consider the sub-group $H$ (in our case $SO(3,1)$) which is the stabilizer of $M$ such that the quotient of the two is a coset/homogenous space:

$$\frac{G}{H}=\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$$

Now we have a connection 1-form $\omega\in h$, the Lie algebra of $H$ and solder form $\theta$ such that $\left(\theta,\omega\right)\in G$. Our tetrad/vierbein $e$ then acts as a map relating the tangent spaces at a point $p$ $T_{p}()$:

$$e:T(M)\rightarrow T(\frac{G}{H})$$

And we end up with the familiar relation:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=e_{\mu}^{a}e_{\nu}^{b}\eta_{ab}$$

It would seem by this construction that the homogenous “model” space would always have to be $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ for a pseudo-Riemannian spacetime; however in perusing the [method of moving frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame)  it's stated that:

> “When the homogenous space is a quotient of special orthogonal groups,
> this reduces to the standard conception of a vierbein. “

Which would seem to imply our homogenous space should be something more like a sphere. Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: Hello am similarly concerned by this subject, actually, I was going to publish a question right now on it, I don't understand your question exactly, but tell me if it's exactly like mine, my question is: How can we relate the canonical form with the tetrad form?

Comment: @intelligible_no even with a bounty no one seems too interested in answering, just keep researching I guess!